# How to increase the value of each element on click

Tags: javascript

How can I increase the value of span on every click and update it with new value? I did increase actually but everytime I click number is only +1;

And it's not updating the value with new one

```js
const imageBelow = document.querySelectorAll('.below-img');
const cocuk = document.querySelectorAll('#cocuk');


imageBelow.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let counter = e.currentTarget.innerText;
    let makeNumber = parseInt(counter)
    makeNumber++
    console.log(makeNumber);

  })
})
```

```html
<div class="below-img">
  <i class="fas fa-retweet"></i>
  <span id="cocuk"> 3 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you point to a specific line of code in the snippet you've provided that you would *expect* to update the DOM with the incremented value?

Comment: `document.getElementById('Id').value=makeNumber';`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `innerText` to the incremented value.

```js
const imageBelow = document.querySelectorAll('.below-img');
const cocuk = document.querySelectorAll('#cocuk');


imageBelow.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    item.innerText = Number(item.innerText) + 1;
    // or +item.innerText + 1;
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="below-img">
  <i class="fas fa-retweet"></i>
  <span id="cocuk"> 3 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now it increases every item that I query and increase the value. how I can make it spesificly " click target " value?

Comment: What do you mean?